# send a form to another component Angular

Tags: angular, components, dataform

hii i want to send a submitted form to another component(Angular) this is my function :

```
}
  onclickval(demande:NgForm){
    this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:9090/demande/createNewDemande/'+ this.cin,demande.value).subscribe((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      this.router.navigate(['accueil/decharge']);//this is where i want to send the created object 
  });
    }
}
```

so after that i can display the infos in the html of the other component i was thinking of sending the response but didn't know how and how to display the infos after. please note that the created object already has another object in it please if can help it would help me a lot and thank you.

Comment: You can't pass an object via route. You could store the informations needed in a `service` and read it - after the navigaiton - from the same service. Be aware that the service **must** be a Singleton.

Comment: Well, this isn't really true. There are some possible solutions, depending on the business logic (e. g. static or dynamic data). See: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-pass-data-to-route/#various-ways-of-passing-route-data

Comment: Well, actually what I meant is that passing an entire complex object as a form is, isn't really a viable solution. Even if the OP would agree on having N parameters in the route's definition there're a lot of topic - not related to Angular itself - that will _enter the chat_. IE: URL pollution and various attacks.  As far the OP wrote he wants to pass the created object via route. The object would not have only just the properties he set but all the `_proto` object in itself, methods, and so on.

Comment: yeah right when i come to think about it you're right, then i shall use the shared service ,thank you